# How do I pass a System.Drawing.Rectangle over WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces, system.drawing

I have a WCF service using a class

```
namespace MyService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class SomeResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public System.Drawing.Rectangle BoundingBox { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On client side, when I try to access the `BoundingBox` rectangle, the Rectangle changed its namespace from `System.Drawing.Rectangle` to `MyServiceReference.Rectangle`.
I would expect the WCF framework to be clever enough to realize that System.Drawing.Rectangle also exists on client side and accordingly use the right namespace. Is it possible to tell the service to do so?

Comment: I think this should answer your question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200346/wcf-service-reference-namespace-differs-from-original

Comment: Hmm... I don't think so. I don't want to change `SomeResponse`'s namespace but the one of `BoundingBox`. And `[DataMember]` does not accept a namespace.

Comment: Woops, wrong link :). Try this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jannemattila/archive/2008/10/15/web-services-and-namespaces-or-wcf.aspx

Comment: Didn't help :( Reuse types in all referenced assemblies was already activated. However, when activating 'Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies', I have no option to choose System.Drawing.

Comment: Argh... my bad! I simply didn't add System.Drawing as a reference to my project!

Comment: Yes, but remember this will only work for basicHttpBinding.

Comment: That's ok, it's all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that WCF uses SOAP to send/received data, which is not directly connected to .net but an open web standard. E.g. a java client might also consume the data and hence not know anything about the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` namespace. It can however use  the Rectangle provided in the Web Service Definition Language and map that to a java Rectangle structure.

In your case, you probably want to cast and convert the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` to `MyServiceReference.Rectangle`. However, WCF provides built-in support for this by checking the "[Reuse types in all referenced assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb628653%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" option in the properties:

> When a service reference is added to a project, any types defined in
>   the service are generated in the local project. In many cases, this
>   creates duplicate types when a service uses common .NET Framework
>   types or when types are defined in a shared library.
>
> To avoid this problem, types in referenced assemblies are shared by
>   default. If you want to disable type sharing for one or more
>   assemblies, you can do so in the Configure Service References dialog
>   box.

This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jannemattila/archive/2008/10/15/web-services-and-namespaces-or-wcf.aspx) provides an example on how to enable/use this functionality.

Finally, make sure that all the right assemblies are referenced in your client application. If it is not referenced, it obviously cannot be re-used by WCF.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I thought the framework was clever enough to map it to a known namespace instead of creating a new one. And it actually does, when 'Reuse types in all referenced assemblies' is checked. My problem was, that System.Drawing was not referenced and thus unknown to my client project. If you edit your anser accordingle, I can accept it :)