# Error "Unbound prefix used in qualified name 'soap:Server'" in Visual Studio for 'wsdl' as a service reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, wsdl

I've added a `wsdl` thing as a service reference in my project.

But when I invoke a method, I do get:

```xml
<Message>Unbound prefix used in qualified name 'soap:Server'.</Message>
```

What it's strange for me (as a newbie):

- in SoapUI 5.6.1 it works OK, the method is returning correctly the information
- the error is when I invoke a method, e.g.:

  ```
   wsdlClient client = new wsdlClient(); // OK

   type[] result = client.getResult(); // Here I get the error
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, it could be your answer: *[Invalid SOAP Fault; Unbound prefix used in qualified name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777656/invalid-soap-fault-unbound-prefix-used-in-qualified-name)*

SoapUI has specialized features to handle WSDL services. That's why adding WCF to a project doesn't mean the same thing.